# Stubbing model method in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, tdd

I am writing test for cotroller but without succes. My test is:

```
describe VideosController do
  describe 'index' do
    it 'should select the index template for rendering' do
      Video.stub(:video_exists?).with("KgfdlZuVz7I").and_return(true)
      get :index, { :q => "KgfdlZuVz7I" }
      response.should render_template('index')
    end
  end
end
```

Here is controller.

```
class VideosController < ApplicationController
  def index
    if params[:q]
      params_hash = CGI::parse(params[:q])
      if Video.video_exists?(params_hash.values[0][0])
        video = Video.new :video_id => params_hash.values[0][0]
        if video.save!
          flash[:notification] = "Video found."
        else
          flash[:notification] = "Video found but not saved to database."
        end
        redirect_to root_path  
      else
        flash[:notification] = "Video not found."
        redirect_to root_path
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Test doesn't pass and it raises message:

> VideosController index should select the index template for rendering
>        Failure/Error: get :index, { :q => "KgfdlZuVz7I" }
>           received :video_exists? with une
>   xpected arguments
>            expected: ("KgfdlZuVz7I")
>                 got: (no args)
>           Please stub a default value first if message might be received with other args as well. 
>        # ./app/controllers/videos_controller.rb:5:in `index'
>        # ./spec/controllers/videos_controller_spec.rb:12:in`block (3 levels) in '

Think I am not stubbing Video on right way, because I stubbed just video_exists? but not new and save. But I don't know how to resolve this since I am new in TDD and Rspec.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As piece of advice #1 you should not write out your "random string" twice like you did in your test.  That is extremely susceptible to mistyping and very difficult to visually verify.  Use this instead:

```
rnd_id = "KgfdlZuVz7I"
Video.stub(:video_exists?).with(rnd_id).and_return(true)
get :index, { :q => rnd_id }
```

Also, I'm not sure what `params_hash = CGI::parse(params[:q])` is supposed to be doing.  Why not just use the params like normal?

```
class VideosController < ApplicationController
  def index
    if params[:q]
      if Video.video_exists?(params[:q])
        video = Video.new :video_id => params[:q]
        if video.save!
          flash[:notification] = "Video found."
        else
          flash[:notification] = "Video found but not saved to database."
        end
        redirect_to root_path  
      else
        flash[:notification] = "Video not found."
        redirect_to root_path
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: For first suggestion you are right.
Second one is not correct. In params[:q] is URL and I am parsing it for one param. For example http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fslkjfas, and I want that string fslkjfas.
Anyway your suggestions doesn't help me to resolve issue with testing.

Comment: Did you actually try my suggestion?  Rails parses the params for you without you needing to do something like this: `CGI::parse(params[:q])`

Comment: I tried and for params[:q] I get http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fslkjfas. I don't want this, but just fslkjfas. Understand now?

Comment: Where in the world is the "youtube.com/watch?v=" coming from?  There is no reference to this url anywhere in your code.

Comment: It's referenced from <input id="q" name="q" type="text">, but it's not important for testing here.

Comment: It sounds like your test is written incorrectly then.  Possibly you need to change `{ :q => "KgfdlZuVz7I" }` to `{ :q => "http://youtube.com/watch?v=KgfdlZuVz7I" }`

Comment: You are right about that. Now I get error: ` Failure/Error: response.should render_template('index')
       expecting <"index"> but rendering with <"">`

Comment: Your test is asserting `response.should render_template('index')` but you are redirecting in your controller.  Change to: `response.should redirect_to(root_path)`